# Google Script Collect dates from a specific column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I have a book of 12 sheets. There are start and end dates on each column. I need script to go through all the sheets (I found how to do this), collect data from the desired column (G) (although there may be empty values and text by the date) and, if at least one overdue date is detected, send an email to the specified mail.

So far, that's all I could write:

```
function checkDate() {


  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  for (var sheet of sheets) {
    var column = sheet.getRange('G:G');
    var values = column.getValues();
     
  GmailApp.sendEmail(me, 'Check date', ssPersonal.getUrl());

  
  
  }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the values in G are dates not "text by date". And do your dates include time?

```
function checkDate() {

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var today = new Date();  // includes time

  for (var sheet of sheets) {
    var column = sheet.getRange(1,7,sheet.getLastRow(),1);
    var values = column.getValues();
    for( var i=0; i<values.length; i++ ) {
      if( values[i][0] === "" ) {
        continue;
      }
      else if( values[i][0] < today ) {  // assuming your values are dates
        GmailApp.sendEmail(me, 'Check date '+sheet.getName(), ssPersonal.getUrl());
        break;
      }
    }
  }
    
}
```